# iPhone OS SDK: Possible to download SDK 3.0 w/o Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I recently downloaded the iPhone SDK 4 along with Xcode and neglected to install 3.0 and 3.1. I've since deleted the install package. I of course can re-download the whole package, but for future reference, I wonder if you are able to download individual SDK versions separately and independent of Xcode, like you would with almost any open source package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to download just the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

If such a thing were available there would be a link to it on the downloads page.

Comment: The Developer and Connect websites have different downloads available, so this answer is inaccurate. The Developer site shows only the latest version of Xcode bundled with the SDK plus a beta version if available. The Connect site shows most past versions of Xcode independent of the SDK.

Comment: Sounds pretty accurate to me.

Comment: While it's true that in this case the package I wanted is unavailable, in many other cases it simply takes digging further. 

I like your logo and website by the way, they both look slick.